# What are the advantages of running multiple instances of mysql on different ports?

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project that has multiple instances of mysql running on different ports (3306, 3307, 3308) the variation in ports was the reason for usernames and passwords and passwords being rejected, however Im not sure why a system administer would choose to do this, can someone help clarify why you would run multiple instances of MySQL which can potentially lead to confusion about usernames and privileges on the differing instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Utilize existing hardware properly - 
   Currently in a standard set up, MySQl queries run in a single thread,(http://lists.mysql.com/internals/37589) having multiple instances give the opportunity to make better use of your hardware, particualrly CPU cores. If your application uses a number of databases that involve a lot of connections then splitting the different databases over different ports allows you to utilise your hardware more efficiently. Also regarding replication, multiple versions can be used to support slaves, "Scale-out solutions - spreading the load among multiple slaves to improve performance. In this environment, all writes and updates must take place on the master server. Reads, however, may take place on one or more slaves. This model can improve the performance of writes (since the master is dedicated to updates), while dramatically increasing read speed across an increasing number of slaves." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html
2. Run multiple versions - 
   Having multiple instances also allows you to have various versions available to a developer for testing and integration purposes. "In some cases, you might want to run multiple instances of MySQL on a single machine. You might want to test a new MySQL release while leaving an existing production setup undisturbed. Or you might want to give different users access to different mysqld servers that they manage themselves. (For example, you might be an Internet Service Provider that wants to provide independent MySQL installations for different customers.)" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-servers.html
3. Reduce Licensing Hardware / OS costs & Smaller/manageable data centre foot print & generally reduced overhead - If you are concerned about licences on the hardware or the OS then the ability to run multiple instances of an application on a single machine will appeal as obviously you would not require additional machines and operating systems to run more versions, also reducing support and maintenance costs of separate machines.

Here is an excellent article on the implementation of said approach, the main points I confess gave the structure to this answer: http://opensourcedbms.com/dbms/running-multiple-mysql-5-6-instances-on-one-server-in-centos-6rhel-6fedora/

Comment: As for number 1. it sounds logical to me but I couldn't find any comparisons for multi mysqld vs. on big innodb running on the same large hardware. Maybe any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Could be Development, Test and Production instances.

(although I would probably have just one, with development, test and production *databases*).